# Detectar qué input realiza el evento focusout con un mismo event listener

Tags: javascript, web

estoy montando un pequeño proyecto y me ha surgido el siguiente problema;
Tengo dos inputs de texto.

```
<input type="text" id="typeAmount" name="typeAmount" placeholder="Enter your bill">
<input type="text" id="peopleCounter" name="peopleCounter" placeholder="Enter a Number">
```

Lo que quiero que ocurra es que, una vez el usuario le quite el focus al input (es decir, el evento de focusout ocurra) una variable predefinida u otra se actualice dependiendo de que input utilizó el usuario.

Para esto he pensado en simplemente hacer lo siguiente:

```
let bill = document.getElementById("typeAmount")
bill.addEventListener("focusout", () => {
    variable1 = bill.value
})

let people = document.getElementById("peopleCounter")
peopleCounter.addEventListener("focusout", () => {
    variable2 = peopleCounter.value
})
```

Todo funciona perfectamente, el problema es que de esta forma debería crear 2 eventListeners, uno para cada input. A alguien se le ocurre alguna manera de obtener el mismo resultado con un mismo eventListener?

He pensado en hacerlo con el parametro de la arrow funcion pero no se me ocurre forma de identificar qué input fue el que sufrio el unfocus sin usar 2 event listeners diferentes, uno por cada input

Comment: el listener con el focusout debe de apuntar a cualquier input.

Comment: bueno pongamos que el eventlistener afecta a todo el document, como hago para idenfiticar que input sufrió el evento?

Comment: puedes caclarar si cada value debe ir en una variable distinta??? esto no me hace sentido... `variable1 = bill.value` luego `variable2 = peopleCounter.value`

Comment: quieres hacer track sobre el input a cual le dio click el usuario (focus)??? de ser asi; si usa una variable de cadena ... se sobre escribira el nombre o valor del input, lo recomendable seria crear un objeto en donde ir agregando la propiedades del input usado y el ultimo valor que contubo ... me dejas saber que es exactamente lo que buscas...

Comment: Hay una diferente variable asociada a cada input value

Comment: bueno hay te di una respuestas ... me avisas si te funciona ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok se me ocurre hacer un tracking de la siguiente forma:

```js
var changesData = {};

document.querySelectorAll('.focusable-validator').forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('focusout', (e) => {
    let element = e.currentTarget;
    changesData[element.name] = element.value;
    console.log(changesData)
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="text" class="focusable-validator" id="typeAmount" name="typeAmount" placeholder="Enter your bill">
<input type="text" class="focusable-validator" id="peopleCounter" name="peopleCounter" placeholder="Enter a Number">
```

Como podras observar he creado un objeto en donde ir guardando los input a los que se le hace el focus out y cual es su ultimo valor.

Comment: Gracias. La respuesta en sí no es exactamente lo que buscaba, pero ver el razonamiento que has usado me ha ayudado a poner en otra perspectiva el mío y he acabado resolviendo el problema. Tampoco se me había pasado por la cabeza lo del event.currentTarget